# How to use async delegate in ASP.NET MVC 2 request?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous, delegates

I need to execute a method in an async mode. I've tried creating a delegate, but the session is destroyed after the request is completed. This function needs to continue running after this, and be able to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Is there a workaround which would allow a method running asynchronously to continue executing after a request has completed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate (for example with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`) but you need to grab reference to the `HttpSessionStateBase` outside of delegate:

```
HttpSessionStateBase session = Session;

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    // You can access session variable here
    ...
});
```

The session will not be destroyed till you hold the reference. There is a simple sample available here: [Reporting server side operation progress with jQuery UI Progressbar](http://tpeczek.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/reporting-server-side-operation.html).

Comment: In the method used by the delegate I call another method which use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session. I can't use this example.

Comment: @Emanuel It will not work because at this point there is no current HttpContext. You need to grab what you require before the delegate and pass it as parameters to any methods etc. (it will be properly serialized/deserialized later but you need to remember about using HttpSessionStateBase.SyncRoot for synchronization of parallel access).